# Simple threading question, locking access to shared resource or entire function?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, critical-section

This is a paraphrasing of a question I had before. It's a simple threading question but I can't seem to understand it.

If i have shared code:

```
private static object objSync = new object();
private int a = 0;

    public void function()
    {
    lock(objSync)
      a += 2;

    lock(objSync)
      a += 3;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    a=0;
    }
```

I can't expect 'a' to equal 5 in the end because the first thread gains a lock sets 'a' to 2 and then then the next thread can get a lock set it to '4' before the first thread is able to add 3 and you'll end up with 7 in the end.

The solution as I understand it would be to put a lock around the entire thing and then you could always expect 5. Now my question is what if between the two locks there is a a million lines of code. I can't imagine putting a lock around a million lines of code. How would you ensure thread safety but not take the fail to performance by putting a lock around a million and two lines of code?

EDIT:

This is nonsense code that I wrote for the question. The actual application is a line monitoring system. There are two screens that show the current line, one for the clerks and one for the public. The screen for the clerk accepts 'clicks' through the serial  port which progresses the line by one and then updates the public screen through a notify event (see observer design pattern). The problem is they aren't synchronized if you spam the clicker. I imagine what's happening is the first screen adds to the line number, displays it and then updates the public screen, but before the public screen has a chance to show the line number from the database, the clerk clicks again and the number goes out of synch. The 'a' above represents a value I retrieve from the db and not just a simple int. There are a few places that I change the value and I need all of it to happen atomically.

Comment: If you don't want two threads to modify the same variable why are you using the same variable in both threads?

Comment: I want two threads to modify the same variable, just atomically, meaning I want the first thread to finish with both assignments before the second thread starts.

Comment: "I can't imagine putting a lock around a million lies of code" implies to me that you haven't tested it. When you are writing multi-threaded code, write the simplest code possible that is guaranteed to give you the correct behavior and then test it. If the performance doesn't meet requirements, then start looking for optimizations. A first iteration of the code that just holds the lock for the length of the function is a reasonable place to start.

Comment: The problem is that I wrote the program and only now do I see there is a problem with synchronization and I'm trying to go back and find the problem.

Comment: @Hightechrider You're right regarding the example that I gave with a simple integer, but I'm really getting that value from the db.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what you define as "success". If it is a counter, that could still be the right result. If you only want to update it if it is what you *thought* it was, then take a snapshot inside the first lock, and likewise compare to the snapshot in the final lock. In that scenario you can replace much of the code with some  Interlocked.CompareExchange. Likewise in the "counter" scenario, Interlocked.Increment is your friend.

If the code **must** match, then you have a few options:

- if the compare fails, run the entire million lines again; repeat until you win the race (by matching)
- if the compare fails, throw an exception
- block for the million lines; it might still be a fast million lines...
- think of some other resolution strategy that makes sense for your scenario

In the first two you should watch for polluting things by leaving any related data in an intermediate state.

And btw; the final assignment to 0 should probably *also* be part of the same locking strategy. Locks only work if all access respects them.

But only your scenario can tell us what the "right" behaviour in a conflict is.

Comment: It's not really a counter, although you answered my example (thank you) in the actual program 'a' is a line number from the db, i.e. it must be shared and I can't have a thread changing it without my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of design actually. If your method calculates different values for "a", depending on certain circumstances, but you do not want another thread changing "a"'s value while an operation is active, something like this is more appropriate:

```
private static object objSync = new object();
private int a = 0;

    public void function()
    {
      int b;
      lock(objSync)
        b = a;
      b += 2;

      //million lines of code

      b +=3;
      lock(objSync)
      {
        a = b;
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        a=0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: that's some good advice and you answered my original question. The problem is the actual code isn't an integer but a line number I retrieve from the database. Even if I make a copy, another thread can change the value in the db and then what I'm showing is an old copy that doesn't represent what's in the db.

Comment: Also with your code what if the first thread sets a to 6, you lock it set b to 6 and release the lock. The next thread comes before the first thread finishes and it says 'a' = 99, so now b instead of 8, it equals 101 and then 3 is added and another thread comes and with a different value of a and changes b to something else, how do you prevent this? You would have to lock the whole thing but I change the value of 'a' in many places as it's a number in the db.